# Why does 1 Chronicles 6 not mention Meraioth?

Tags: genealogy, 1-chronicles

1 Chronicles 6 does not mention Meraioth who is mentioned in 1 Chronicles 9:11 and Nehemiah 11:11:

```
   1 Chr 6     1 Chr 9:11
   --------    -----------
 6 Meraioth
   Amariah
 7 Ahitub                 
 8 Zadok
   Ahimaaz
 9 Azariah
   Johanan
10 Azariah 
11 Amariah
   Ahitub      Ahitub
               Meraioth
12 Zadok       Zadok
   Shallum     Meshullam
13 Hilkiah     Hilkiah
   Azariah     Azariah
```

What is the reason for the omission?

Interestingly, 1. Chr 6:6 *does* mention another(?) Meraioth, yet this one is born *before* any Ahitub.

Answer (score 1):

James T. Sparks (*[The Chronicler's Genealogies: Towards an Understanding of 1 Chronicles 1-9](https://books.google.com.au/books?id=jwh415r7YFoC&pg=PA76&dq=Meraioth%20bible%20omits&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjLw8LRqYLSAhVGGZQKHdhgD0oQ6AEIMDAE#v=onepage&q=Meraioth%20&f=false)*) discusses the genealogies in some depth, pointing out (*ibid*, page 77 that similar genealogies also appear in the books of Nehemiah and Ezra:

> [image]

Sparks discusses the evolution of the priestly lists, explaining that the chronologically later lists were made to demonstrate that Aaron were included in the priestly genealogies. We can suppose that some minor variations in these genealogies occurred as part of this process of evolution. On page 346, Sparks says:

> It is probable, then, that the priestly lists in 1 Chr 9:11 and Neh 11:11 represent a tradition of the preexilic priesthood that had not yet been telescoped with the deletion of Meraioth.